# Populate the same sys_refcursor in different loops

Tags: oracle, plsql

My code has a SYS_REFCURSOR that needs populated with the values contained in 2 standard CURSORs.

I've populated SYS_REFCURSOR first fetching/loop in the first CURSOR, and then, fetching/loop the second cursor.

p_datos is the SYS_REFCURSOR.

```
OPEN cursor1;
LOOP FETCH cursor1 INTO X,Y,Z;
OPEN p_datos FOR
    X,
    Y,
    Z;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor1;

OPEN cursor2;
LOOP FETCH cursor2 INTO X,Y,Z;
OPEN p_datos FOR
    X,
    Y,
    Z;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor2;
```

I've assumed that the SYS_REFCURSOR is not closed and it is always open to add registers to it, but my doubt is if the registers from the 1st cursor are overwrited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ref cursor is replaced every time you open it, so you'll only get the result of the very last fetch in cursor 2. (Assuming you're really doing `open ... select x,y,z from dual` inside the loop, which isn't entirely clear from your pseudocode...). Are you doing anything else with the cursor1/2 or their results? The simplest thing is just to combine their queries into a single ref-cursor open, but again unclear if that will work for you form your pseudocode. Maybe a more realsitic example would help.

Comment: Thanks very much, with your comment "The ref cursor is replaced every time you open it" it's all clear for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: A ref cursor isn’t really “populated”. It represents a set in terms of the instructions needed to fetch it.